# Extract substring from array of strpos values

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I have the following string

```
$string = "Hello World!<br />- 8/7/2013<br />Content<br />- 8/6/2013<br />Hello World";
```

I want to extract all the information between the dash + space ("- ") and the next line break tag. Is that possible? I've been researching Google for hours but no luck. I'm thinking that I need an array of strpos of the "- " and the following line break tag and then batch substr them. But of course if you can do this any other way, that would be so much appreciated!

Comment: It's possible. First you `strpos` for a `'- '`, then for `'<br'` then `substr`

Comment: @zerkms Are you sure that would be possible whn there are multiple occurances? I don't want just the first one, I want to extract all the substrings. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can do that in a loop. One occurrence by one. If you don't know regular expressions - it's the simple and trivial to implement solution

Comment: @David you say you want to match all occurances, but there's only one occurrence in your example. The second date isn't prefixed by "`- `", but just "`-`".

Comment: @kba Sorry about that -- fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've updated my answer to handle multiple occurances.**

You can do this with a simple regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("@- (.*)<br />@U", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The above will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8/7/2013
    [1] => 8/6/2013
)
```

This matches the pattern `- (.*)<br />` with `(.*)` meaning *anything*. The `@`s here work as delimiters to separate the actual pattern with the modifiers (in this case `U` meaning an ungreedy match).

Comment: thanks so much for the response! I do have a question: when I write $match[1];, it indeed returns the first occurrence of the substring. But when I write $match[2], which I assume it should return the second occurrence, it doesn't. Any solution to that?

Comment: Teriffic, thank you! This is helping a lot. Eventually I want to get to the point where the matches will be found in the original string, and added a bold tag in front + end bold tag at the end of each substring. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You should just have asked that to begin with. :-) `$string = preg_replace("@- (.*)<br />@U", "- <strong>$1</strong><br />", $string);`.

Comment: You're right -- I'm sorry -- I haven't used Stack Overflow that much but will ask next time that to begin with! Anyway, How exactly can this work? When I have the complete code, there are two $string variables...
$string = "Hello World!<br />- 8/7/2013<br />Content<br />- 8/6/2013<br />Hello World";
$string = preg_replace("@- (.*)<br />@U", "- <strong>$1</strong><br />", $string);
print_r($matches[1]);

Comment: Yes, `$string` is the input data. After you do $string = preg_replace(...);`, the dates will be bolded. Try it out.

Comment: Also, I can see you have asked 5 questions, but only accepted an answer to one question. Please accept the correct answer in each question.

Comment: Accepted the answer -- thanks for catching that. When I try though, this is what I get: http://codepad.org/O1LKKljx
Is there anything I'm not getting... :(? Thanks so much!

Comment: http://codepad.org/WebG0hMz. You were outputting `$string[1]`, but snince `$string` isn't an array, that'll be the second character `e`.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions will give you the most control, but here is a quick demo using strpos and substr to get what you asked for:

```
$strStart = strpos($string, '- ');
$strLength = strpos($string, '<br') - $strStart;
substr( $string, $strStart, $strLength );
```